# SQL : How do I sum all null values into another value of specific row?

Tags: mysql, sql, null, sum

I am using Mysql.

I have 2 tables:

1. table Sales:

   ```
   S_Id    DATE       Total_Price    Employee_Id
   1       1/02/2014  5636           10
   2       1/04/2014  148            999
   3       1/05/2014  101            30
   4       1/06/2014  959            40
   5       1/02/2014  3000           10
   6       1/04/2014  4992           13
   7       1/05/2014  472            11
   8       1/06/2014  8483           40
   ```
2. table employees:

   ```
   Employee_Id  First_Name    Last_Name    Address     City 
   10           brock         li           a1          berlin
   20           dan           santiago     a2          london
   30           alex          brookmen     a3          rome
   40           michael       gold         a4          amsterdam
   50           john          bisping      a5          barcelona
   999          tony          oneale       a6          munich
   ```

   - the employees table holding only active employees
   - but still the table Sales holding all sales, including sales of not active employees

my question:

1. I want to make the top 4 employees who made the max of sum sales per only active employees (by sum Sales.Total_Price) at year 2015
2. Employee_Id = 999 will include his sum of sales and also the sum of all the Sales price that made by not active employees.

   - Employee_Id = 999 is an active employee

therefor result should be:

```
Employee_Id  First_Name    Last_Name    Address     City    total sales  
10               brock         li          a1       berlin      8636  
20               dan           santiago    a2       london      8483 
999              tony          oneale      a6       munich      5612
40               michael       gold        a4       amsterdam   959
```

therefor I tried to make a left join between table Sales to employees and sum all the prices when employees.Employee_Id = null

my code:

```
SELECT s.employee_id
     , e.first_name
     , e.last_name
     , e.address
     , e.city
     , CASE WHEN ISNULL(e.employee_id) OR e.employee_id = 999 
            THEN SUM(s.total_price) 
            ELSE SUM(s.total_price) END 'total sales'
  FROM sales s
  LEFT 
  JOIN employees e
    ON s.employee_id = e.employee_id
 WHERE YEAR(s.date) = 2015
 GROUP 
    BY s.employee_id
     , e.first_name
     , e.last_name
 ORDER 
    BY SUM(s.total_price) DESC
 LIMIT 4
```

but it didn't succeed:

1. it didn't sum all the sales of null values (not active employees) into the row of Employee_Id = 999
2. it still can be that not active employees will be presented in the top 4 sales when I only want active employees in the list
3. also, if you know a better way to sum max 4 sales per employee it will be great for me to learn

Comment: Sample data and desired results (and a db fiddle!) would really help.  Your question is totally confusing.  Do you want four employees or four sales?  Do you always want employee 999 or not?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I added data so you can more understand my question. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to first sum all the details from sales table and then use left join. Something like below might help you -

```
 SELECT E2.*, Total_Sales
 FROM (SELECT emp.employee_id
             ,SUM(total_price) Total_Sales
       FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN e.employee_id IS NULL OR e.employee_id = 999 THEN 999 ELSE s.employee_id END employee_id
                  , e.first_name
                  , e.last_name
                  , e.address
                  , e.city
                  , s.total_price
             FROM Sales s
             LEFT JOIN employees e ON s.employee_id = e.employee_id) emp
             GROUP BY emp.employee_id) s2
 JOIN employees E2 on s2.employee_id = E2.employee_id
 ORDER BY s.total_sales DESC
 LIMIT 4
```

Here is the Db-Fiddle -

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=748fd944384d80e717c08b3a2057f5c6

Answer (score 0):

thank you Ankit Bajpai, this is the final answer

```
select  employees.*, Total_Sales
from    (select emp.Employee_Id,
        sum(Total_Price) as 'Total_Sales'
        from    (select case when employees.employee_id is null or employees.Employee_Id = 999 then 999 else Sales.Employee_Id end Employee_Id,
                Sales.Total_Price
                from      actiview_task.Sales                  
                left join actiview_task.employees
                on        Sales.Employee_Id = employees.Employee_Id
                where year(DATE)= 2015) emp
         group by emp.Employee_Id) empGroupBy
join actiview_task.employees on empGroupBy.Employee_Id = employees.Employee_Id
order by Total_Sales desc
limit 4
```